# Populating array with SecureRandom: Why not out of bounds?

Tags: java, arrays, random, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to populate an array (probCount) using a SecureRandom object (index) to determine probabilities. I have a for loop to run this about 100 million times:

```
probCount[index.nextInt(probCount.length)]++;
```

When I print the array, all my elements are populated correctly. How does this line does not throw an out of bounds exception?

I had it like:

```
probCount.length - 1
```

This, however, never populated my last element. I am a bit confused.

Comment: Did you read the javadoc?

Comment: Yes,  I read and obviously missed something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`Random.nextInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) documentation:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)
>
> ...
>
> Parameters:
> `bound` - the upper bound (exclusive). Must be positive.

Note the "exclusive" part. So for example, if you call `index.nextInt(5)` it will return 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4... which are precisely the valid indexes for an array of length 5.

Comment: I definitely missed that. I guess I should go back and change all those -1 I've been using.

Comment: @Alexander: Almost certainly, yes. Upper bounds in APIs are *typically* exclusive. (Look at String.substring for example.)

Comment: @Alexander: Yes, absolutely. Look at `List.subList` for example.

Comment: Wow. I've been doing things wrong for a while now but never noticed the difference until now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the documentation for Random.nextInt(n), it explains that the value is between 0 (inclusive) and n (exclusive).

Documentation is your friend.